# How to Recompile Deconstructed EXE

Tags: java, recompile

I had some software developed on oDesk about a year ago. What I get back is a java based .EXE

It runs as a standalone without any sort of installation. The problem is they screwed up some graphics for the buttons, it didn't bother me at the time, because I got what I wanted, a minimal viable product that got the job done.

With that said, it's been bothering me for a while, and when I reach back out to the guy - I can't get him.

I used 7zip to open the .EXE and extracted all the contents. I found where the buttons were and fixed them, obviously trying to drag it into 7Zip in the specified location isn't going to work.

How do I go about recompiling everything?

I'm new to all this, so if you need any additional information, please don't hesitate to ask. I just want this thing to look as I intended.

Comment: 7Zip to "open an exe"? you mean rather an executable zip?

Comment: Is this actually a `.jar` file? Perhaps Windows displays it as an "executable Java file"?

Comment: No, it's an executable file. That's what it says in the properties, and when I open it, it runs the software.

It was developed in java. 

This is also besides the point. What I have is all the files that make up the .EXE, and I'm looking to find out how to re-compile it after making some changes to the button images.

Comment: And yes, if you open 7Zip, navigate to a folder with a .EXE, you can right click on that .EXE and click "Open Inside" to explore, and yes, even copy all the files that make up the .EXE

So now, I just need to put things back together. Any advice?